# Use pgfplots \addplot plot coordinates with relative coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

I want to use in `pgfplots` `\addplot plot cordinates` with relative coordinates. However the following syntax doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
      \addplot plot coordinates {(0,0) ++(2,2) ++(1,3)};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I make this (or something similar) work?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73792/relative-coordinates-in-pgfplots-across-multiple-table-plots

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you provide your data as a table instead of as a list of coordinates, you can use `pgfplotstable` to define a new column that consists of the accumulated x and y values:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/x rel/.style={
        create col/expr={
            \pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{0}
        }
    },
    create on use/y rel/.style={
        create col/expr={
            \pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{1}
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x = x rel, y=y rel] {
      0 0
      2 2
      1 3
     };
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. When I add a % sign at the end of the table lines to prevent emacs to mash up my formatting, it doesn't compile. Do you have any tip for this?

Comment: You can add `ignore chars=\%` to the `table` options.