# Relative coordinates in pgfplots across multiple table plots

Tags: pgfplots

This is a follow up question to this one: [Use pgfplots \addplot plot coordinates with relative coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73774/use-pgfplots-addplot-plot-coordinates-with-relative-coordinates)

Is it also possible to have the relative coordinates across multiple plots?

For example if I take @Jake's answer:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x = x rel, y=y rel,ignore chars=\%] {
      0 0 %absolute (0,0)
      2 2 %absolute (2,2)
      1 3 %absolute (2,2) + (1,3) = (3,5)
     };
     \addplot table [x = x rel, y=y rel,ignore chars=\%] {
      1 1 %absolute (3,5) + (1,1) = (4,6)
      2 1 %absolute (4,6) + (2,1) = (6,7)
     };
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Alternatively it would also suffice to be able to specify in the table that the path between two specific successive coordinates should not be drawn.

Comment: Can you add a little bit of background information about what you're trying to achieve? In this simple example, it's not clear why you would need two different `\addplot` commands, for example.

Comment: I don't want a line between the absolute coordinates (3,5) and (4,6) in my example. So I just tried to use two `\addplots`

Comment: Could you just manually adjust the first coordinate in the second `\addplot` command (in this case, using `4 6` instead of `1 1`)?

Comment: Instead of using the `pgfplotstable` approach you can use `\draw (axis cs: 0,0) -- ++ (axis direction cs: 2,2) 
                           -- ++ (axis direction cs:1,3)
                           -- ++ (axis direction cs:1,1)
                           -- ++ (axis direction cs:2,3);` which allows you to delete the appropriate `--`. I'm not sure if this is the direction (pun intended) you want to go though...

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to continue the previous curve with a new one, so I cooked up semi-automatic style but can be automated by placing a node in the end of the previous curve converting its coordinates into axis coordinates and supplying to the next as the initial point.

It mainly abuses the `expr accum` column type with an initial value. You need to add a zero row before resuming though.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/x rel/.style={create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{0}}},
    create on use/y rel/.style={create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{1}}},
    x resume/.style={create on use/xrelr/.style={create col/expr accum={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{0}}{#1}},x=xrelr},
    y resume/.style={create on use/yrelr/.style={create col/expr accum={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{1}}{#1}},y=yrelr},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x = x rel, y=y rel] {
      0 0
      2 2
      3 4
     };
     \addplot table [x resume = 5, y resume = 6] {
      0 0
      5 -4
      9 3
     };
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]